# UPDATE not updating values in my database

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

```
c.execute('UPDATE tickets SET ayudante=? WHERE numeroTicket=?', (nombre_ayudante, numero_ticket))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
return
```

I'm trying to update a single cell from a row and I can't get it right. When I select the same row after the update, the value is still the same as before.

Comment: Are you sure you're passing the correct `numero_ticket`?

Comment: Pretty sure, because I'm doing a select right before the update for a check.
("SELECT numeroTicket, idUsuario FROM tickets WHERE numeroTicket=?", (numero_ticket,)):'

Comment: Try capturing the rows affected with ```cursor.rowcount```, as a sanity check to ensure a row (or rows) were actually affected.

Comment: Got it right, was working with discord.py and one embed was causing problems. Thank you for your comments!